# How should supportsInterface be implemented for interfaces with multiple levels of inheritance in ERC165?

Tags: solidity, interfaces, eip-165

When an interface has multiple levels of inheritance, should the `supportsInterface` in ERC165 checks the entire entire inheritance stack of the interface or just the top-most level?

Here's an example. Let's say I have an interface `IAnimal` and another interface `ICat` which implements `IAnimal` like this:

```
interface IAnimal {
  function walk() external;
  function run() external;
}

interface ICat is IAnimal {
   function meow() external;
   function jumps() external;
}
```

Then, I have a ERC165 contract that uses `ICat`:

```
contract MyContract is ERC165, ICat {
  // Implements interface methods of both ICat and IAnimal because ICat implements IAnimal...

  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) external view returns (bool) {
    // How should the check here be like?
  }
}
```

My question is, how should I implement the check in `supportsInterface` in this case?

**Should the check in `supportsInterface` match the interface ID of *only* the methods in `ICat` *excluding* `IAnimal`? Or should the check here match the interface ID of *all* methods in both `ICat` and `IAnimal` since `ICat` extends `IAnimal`?**

- If the check only has to match the interface ID of the methods, I could do this:

  ```
  return interfaceId == type(ICat).interfaceId || interfaceId == type(IAnimal).interfaceId;
  ```
- However, if the check has to match the interface ID of all methods in both `ICat` and `IAnimal`, how should I combine the interface ID from both interfaces?

  - I notice that `type(ICat).interfaceId` will ignore the methods in `IAnimal` when computing the interface ID. In other words, the interface ID is only computing the methods `meow()` and `jumps()` in `ICat` but doesn't include `walk()` and `run()` in `IAnimal`! This is surprising to me because **`type().interfaceId` seems to ignore any inherited methods in the interface?** So I can't use `type(ICat)`.
  - I tried something like this but this doesn't seem correct:

    ```
    return interfaceId == type(IAnimal).interfaceId || interfaceId == (type(ICat).interfaceId ^ type(IAnimal).interfaceId);
    ```

I haven't found any examples on ERC165 with multiple levels of inheritance with its interface, not even in its EIP doc.